# Responsive Design and Article Element

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've got a page, with three sections.  Each section is an  that takes the entire view of the page.  I would like the article and background to fit within the mobile device screen, as it does on a desktop, but can't figure out how to get the article to adjust.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kRjUn/

Here's the CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    }

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    height: 100%;
}

article {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 2em;
    }
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: inherit;
    }

.content {
    margin-top: 25em;
    height: inherit;
    }
```

Comment: Why not try [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: I have the same problem, and no one has been able to help me with this. It seems that when you set the height to 100%, it only sets it to 100% of the "viewport", not the parent element. At the moment, I don't think this can be done.

Comment: I could go that route, I was hoping that I could just find the device's height and adjust accordingly instead of multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

I found this gridless boilerplate, and set the body height to 100% and it seemed to work great.  I also just used a div instead of article.  Anyone looking for a clean and responsive boilerplate I would def. give this one a shot: https://github.com/thatcoolguy/gridless-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

What i feel that you code is not handling case for each devices, you need to use CSS 3 media query feature which can help you.

I think you can use [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) template as example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, use display tables.

```
article {
   height: 100%;
   padding-top: 2em;
   display: table;
}
.wrapper.content { 
    padding: 2em; 
    display: table-cell;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/kRjUn/1/)